# No Such Element in Client Class

Tags: java, nosuchelementexception

I am working on an assignment for school, and ran into a problem that I have spent hours on figuring out how to fix. The link is to my project. If you run it, it will come up with an error after you enter one of  the choices. 
Thank you in advance, I wont be surprised if it is a simple error but cannot seem to figure it out.

https://repl.it/@kirillpenkov/Final-Assignment

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include relevant source code here in the form of a [mcve]. When you ran this using a debugger what did you figure out?

Comment: Have you tried to debug and find out what the place of your code leads this error?

Comment: No I dont know how to use a debugger.